# node.js ncp (async recursive copy utility) callback not called

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and maybe I am doing something wrong.
There's this hugely popular async recursive copy utility npmjs.org/package/ncp.

I am trying to run it in parallel:

```
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;

var dirs = [
    ['test/from/1', 'test/to/1'],
    ['test/from/2', 'test/to/2'],
    ['test/from/3', 'test/to/3']
];

var copyDirAsync = function (dir) {
    ncp(dir[0], dir[1], function (err) {
        console.log('done: ' + dir[1]);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; ++i) {
    copyDirAsync(dirs[i]);
}
```

So, all dirs copy just fine. However I get only one console.log message printed with a random directory. The other two don't arrive. The program just exists. If I add a 15 sec timeout so that node keeps running for a while, the callbacks don't arrive either. I would assume that this is a problem with ncp, however with 30K downloads per day of a 1-month old realease 0.5.0, and no issues reported so far, plus me a newcomer to node.js, I'll just assume I don't understand something about node.

Answer (score 3):

First read [Asynchronous iteration patterns](http://metaduck.com/01-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html)

Now, you can use the [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async) module especially `async.series` like so;

```
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp
  , async = require('async');

var dirs = [
    ['test/from/1', 'test/to/1'],
    ['test/from/2', 'test/to/2'],
    ['test/from/3', 'test/to/3']
];

var copyDirAsync = function (dir, done) {
  ncp(dir[0], dir[1], function (err) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    console.log('done: ' + dir[1]);
    done();
  });
}


async.each(dirs, copyDirAsync, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I reduced my example from my app where I used ncp in async.map() where it runs in parallel. I just don't understand why it can't run in parallel?

Comment: Made it working by changing to mapSeries. Still it's not clear about parallel: ncp is a 200-loc function packaged as a closure with no globals defined.